# Plugin for showing cross-sells on the single product page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, e-commerce

I made a custom plugin for showing cross-sells on the single product page in WooCommerce, however i need to know if this is secure and possibly act as an attack vector. Additionally, is there a better way than a while loop for iterating through the products?

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

function show_cross_sell_in_single_product(){
    $crosssells = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_crosssell_ids',true);
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'post__in' => $crosssells
        );
    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $products ) : ?>

        <section class="related products">

          <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Passend dazu', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

          <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

          <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
              wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
          endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

          <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        </section>

      <?php endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

}

add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'show_cross_sell_in_single_product', 10, 2);
/* todo removeaction woocommerce_after_single_product_summary, show_related */
}
```

Comment: If anyone is interested in this code, I updated some things to reflect the comments of @Welcher and put everything on github (https://github.com/agcty/wc-ccs) complete with a description of how to use and customize it.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks ok to me from a security point of view. You're not accessing the database directly and it looks like you are escaping the output ( assuming that the template part does the same ).

A couple of suggestions:

Instead of looking for the filename in the list of active plugins, use `function_exists` or `class_exists` to check to see if the plugin is enabled by looking for a function or class defined by the plugin. The reason being that options can be cached and filenames can be changed. Function/Class names rarely change and it's much cleaner looking.

```
if ( class_exists( 'WC_Query' ) ) {
    // Your plugin code.
}
```

Check to make sure that you're actually getting data returned in `$crosssells = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_crosssell_ids',true);` before using it in the query. If there is no data, there's no point in querying the database.

```
// Put this before the query
$crosssells = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_crosssell_ids',true);    
if ( empty( $crosssells ) {
    return;
}
```

WP_Query will always return something and so `if( $products )` will always be true. Use `if( $products->have_posts() )` instead. This will only return true if there were posts returned from the query.

To answer your question, the `while` loop is fine. That's what WordPress core and the bundled theme use.

The only other suggestion I would make is for performance. Add a couple of items to your query args:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'post__in' => $crosssells,

        /**
         * If you're not paginating, this skips MYSQL_CALC statments
         */
        'no_found_rows' => true,

        /**
         * Skips updating meta cache
         */
        'update_post_meta_cache' => false,

        /**
         * Skips updating term cache.
         */            
         'update_post_term_cache' => false,
    );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes that definitely helps! However I came across two questions: 1)   
    "global $product; $crosssells = $product->get_cross_sell_ids();" seems to be the new standard of getting the cross_sells, just tested it out and it seems to work, is this a viable option? 2) when checking if a certain class like "if ( class_exists( 'WC_Query' ) )" exists, the code wont run, also tried it with WooCommerce and others, how can this be possible when wordpress is activated and i clearly use WP_Query inside the code?